# Appropriate way to implement the base abstract state with Akita

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-akita, akita

I've tried to implement such a thing and I'm a bit confused. Suppose I need to implement variety of grid based page which designed more or less the same way, but each of them has some peculiarities. That's why I need some base abstract store/query services where I am planning to implement common logic.

Each grid will operate with child of `BaseLineItem`:

```
export interface BaseListItem {
  Id: number;
  StatusId: number;
  // Other properties
}
```

That the way I try to implement it

```
export interface PageState<TListItem extends BaseListItem> extends EntityState<TListItem> {
  // some state properties
}

export abstract class PageStore<TListItem extends BaseListItem, TState extends PageState<TListItem>> extends EntityStore<TState> {
  constructor(initialState: Partial<TState>) {
    super(initialState);
  }

  addNewItems(items: TListItem[]): void {
    this.upsertMany(items);
  }
}
```

It's supposed that for each form I will implement children for line item, state and store, so I can have possibilities to add some peculiarities which are specific for each form. But in that place I've faced with a problem in `addNewItems` method - `upsertMany`, which shows the following error:

```
Argument of type 'TListItem[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'getEntityType<TState>[]'.\n  Type 'TListItem' is not assignable to type 'getEntityType<TState>'.\n    Type 'BaseListItem' is not assignable to type 'getEntityType<TState>'.
```

It seems that Akita are not able to infer the type for entity.

That is the question. How to solve this problem, without using `as any` everywhere(If I start to do it in the very base level, I will lost intellisense across the source code)? I came to the front-end world from the .Net background.  Maybe I don't understand something and this architecture pattern isn't the best here? And I need some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EntityStore.upsertMany](https://github.com/datorama/akita/blob/bd2c6aebd3fd10b1c2925a41a1b2d012842bde85/libs/akita/src/lib/entityStore.ts#L307) method takes as a parameter array of `EntityType[]` which was inferred by using typescript helper type

```
export class EntityStore<S extends EntityState = any, EntityType = getEntityType<S>,
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's [the source code](https://github.com/datorama/akita/blob/bd2c6aebd3fd10b1c2925a41a1b2d012842bde85/libs/akita/src/lib/types.ts#L56) of this helper:

```
export type getEntityType<S> = S extends EntityState<infer I> ? I : never;
```

[Constrained generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), which you use in your implementation, confuse that helper helper a little and it can't infer correct type and returns `unknown` which doesn't match with your generic type.

Maybe TypeScript will infer types better in future for such cases but for now a simple solution would be using the same Akita helper in your code instead of `TListItem[]`:

```
addNewItems(items: getEntityType<TState>[]): void {
  this.upsertMany(items);
}
```

You can test it in **[Playground](https://ng-run.com/edit/LlCPQVSOfNASd01okHtV?open=app%2Fbooks.store.ts)**

Below is an example of derived class where you can observe correct type inference.

[image]

Also, you can take a look at similar issue in [Akita issue tracker](https://github.com/datorama/akita/issues/432)